# Dart import package:polymer/polymer.dart error

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-pub

I'm trying to create my own element with Polymer, but i can't import polymer package.
[image]

Why it throws error: "Target of URI doesn't exist"?
In Tools Output window I found 404 error.
[image]

And my `pubspec.yaml`:

```
name: polymer1

description: A sample web application
dependencies:
  browser: any
  polymer: ">=0.15.1 < 0.17.0"
```

Comment: When you open the `polymer` folder selected in your first screenshot, does it contain the `polymer.dart` file?

Comment: Yes it contains polymer.dart

Comment: I assume you tried restarting DartEditor?

Comment: also `pub cache repair`, `pub get`?

Comment: A comment to this bug report http://dartbug.com/23147 seems to indicate that this is a cache problem. Try deleting the `.pub` directory in you project directory.

Comment: No but in VirtualBox on Ubuntu it is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your `pub-cache` is corrupted. Try to run `pub cache repair` from the command line.